# Maximum virtual memory allocation for a thread in RHEL6

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, rhel6

As RHEL6 introduced a new arena allocator design because of the same number of arena’s are increased for a single thread which is resulting into more virtual memory usage.
RHEL6 is allocating separate chunks of memory for each thread. Number of Arena per thread are calculated as below as per my understanding on 32/64 bit system:

```
On 32 Bit system  : 
Number of Arena = 2 * Number of cores .
On 64 Bit system :
Number of Arena = 8 * Number of cores .
```

Please validate if my understanding have some gap.

My machine has 4 cores and 64 bit system,

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               759.000
BogoMIPS:              4589.41
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
$ uname -a
Linux admin 3.13.0-71-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 1 02:34:22 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So it has 4*8=32 Arena's per thread. Each arena has a maximum size of 64MB; pet thread virtual memory can be reached to 32*64=2GB(per thread).
Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

I have created a sample program. It is allocated 1.5 GB of heap memory.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *thread(void *arg)
{
  int i=0;
  char *x[1024];
  unsigned int pid;
  char str[15];
  char cmd[30]="cat /proc/";
  pid = getpid();
  sprintf(str, "%d", pid);
  strcat(cmd,str);
  strcat(cmd,"/status");
  system(cmd);
  for(i=0;i<1536;i++)
  {
    x[i] = malloc(1*1024*1024);
    printf("Memory Allocated %d:\n ",i);
    system(cmd);
  }
  for(i=0;i<1536;i++)
  {
    *x[i] = 5;
    free(x[i]);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   unsigned i;
   pthread_t t;
   pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread, NULL);
   pthread_join(t, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

thread t is heap memory allocation is lesser than 2GB. but it generates the coredump after allocating 1GB approx. For more detail please refer the below detail:

```
Name:   arena
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   12511
Ngid:   0
Pid:    12511
PPid:   4417
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
FDSize: 256
Groups: 4 24 27 30 46 108 124 129 1000 
VmPeak:  1133924 kB
VmSize:  1133924 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:      4568 kB
VmRSS:      4568 kB
VmData:  1127636 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:      2012 kB
VmPTE:      2092 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    2
SigQ:   0/46560
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000006
SigCgt: 0000000180000000
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000001fffffffff
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   ff
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-7
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    1027
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 4
```

Why the coredump generated? is my above understanding is incorrect to calculate the thread maximum virtual memory?

Also what are the consequences happened if virtual memory maximum limit reached
Please note I have set ulimit to unlimited

```
$ ulimit
unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the coredump generated?

You have

```
  char *x[1024];
  …
  for(i=0;i<1536;i++)
  {
    x[i] = malloc(1*1024*1024);
```

- a plain case of array overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Memory allocation generally isn't specific to any distribution.  Typically, the allocator is the [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) implementation.  However, the amount of memory a thread can allocate should be a function of the kernel, not the allocator.  Some of the reasons you wouldn't be able to allocate memory might include exhausting physical memory, exhausting swap memory, ulimit, cgroups, etc...

If you still suspect the allocator though, you can try using [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to directly map the memory into the process.

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for answering. Please go through the https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_glibc_2_10_rhel_6_malloc_may_show_excessive_virtual_memory_usage?lang=en

Comment: Jason , I think its not true that VM is not dependent on design of allocator .Typically, block memory allocation is performed using a “partition pool”, which is defined statically or dynamically and configured to contain a specified number of blocks of a specified fixed size.

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL You're incorrect.  Even with thread arenas, the allocator will typically call directly down to the operating system when the requested chunk size is above a certain threshold.  Furthermore, the allocator will not raise a `SIGSEGV` signal.

Comment: @Ajayyadav The article you're pointing to is from 2012, and it's describing some of what I'm talking about.  If you still suspect the allocator, you can use `mmap` to bypass it.

Comment: Jason , did I say anything about the SIGSEGV signal ? Moreover , whatever I said may not be true for you but as far as allocator is concerned , it is true . Source of above information is this link http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/25090/dynamic-memory-allocation-fragmentation-c.html   . Do you have any link or prove for your theory ?

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL The issue with the above code is that it catches a `SIGSEGV` signal.  This is virtual memory 101.  I'm not entirely sure what the goal of your comments are.  Can you give me an idea how what you're describing is relevant to this answer?

Comment: @SACHIN Your article is good enough actually. Because if you read it carefully you'll see that it's dealing with determined allocation in RT OSes. Not very applicable to standard Linux. Real-time has very different requirements to normal applications, you can very rarely map from one to the other.

Comment: Jason , my comment was an answer your comment where you claim "Memory allocation generally isn't specific to any distribution" which unfortunately not true .I hope I am clear now .Anyways , you didn't mention from where you got the information used in your comment ?Would you please let me know the source of ur info if there is any .

Comment: @ Voo , IMO RHEL6 has come up with a new allocator design to avoid the problem of false sharing (which was the problem with RHEL5 allocator ) .Previously , allocator used to share the area if it was not in use .New allocator design will provide separate arena (may be more than one ) for each thread and hence it will not only avoid the "false sharing " but also result into better performance .